# OAuth2 best practice - using Access Tokens

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0

I am implementing an OAuth2 API. I wanted to know what the best practice was in relation to using access_tokens.

Once I authenticate with the API, i receive an access_token that available for 30 minutes, should I be storing that in a database table and then using that for each call until it expires (or I receive an error), and then generate a new access_token?

Or should I simply re-authenticate and receive a new access_token, for each API call? There is a refresh_token available for 7 days but that requires an extra API call the same as authenticating again (unless I am reading incorrectly)

Or is there a more elegant best practice solution that I haven't considered?

Comment: best practice is whatever works for you. Just make sure you store the token securely, if you store it.

Comment: generally the client uses the same token till it expires. This basically avoids unnecessary hits to authentication service. If you plan to store good options are database or a cache, just plan to store them securely and in case of cache handle invalidation properly. I generally store in local cache .